# What do you call an excessively protective environment that stifles innovation?

Tags: phrase-request

I believe I've already asked this question but since I can't search among my own questions, I'll ask it again, I forgot what I was answered with.

What do you call an excessively protective environment that stifles innovation? For example:

> High tariffs created a _______ that made domestic enterprises increasingly fall behind their foreign competitors. Once the tariffs were lifted, many of them were forced to shut down crushed by cheaper and more competitive imports.

Here in Russia, we have the term 'greenhouse conditions'.

Comment: By the way, you can search your own questions with advanced search, e.g. [user:101901 is:q](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A101901+is%3Aq+) finds all your questions, and you can add search terms there.

Comment: @cigien I couldn't find it. I don't know, maybe I asked it elsewhere

Comment: It's also possible that the question might have been deleted. You can find your own deleted posts (up to a certain point in the past) from your profile page.

Comment: It's not an exact fit for the example sentence, but a related term is [hothouse flower](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/30/messages/1268.html) or a flower that can't be grown under natural conditions. It's used metaphorically to refer to people or companies who have gotten so used to being cared for that they don't learn (or forget) how to take care of themselves.

Comment: High import tariffs **stifled** domestic companies, causing them to fall increasingly behind foreign competitors. [I don't much like domestic, better to say our or the country].

Comment: This is a request for industry-specific terminology. Maybe try in [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) or a business-related site?

Comment: Hothouse as a metaphor is tricky; hothouse flower refers to something that can only grow in protected conditions, but in business a hothouse or hothouse atmosphere is one that stimulates ideas and growth in the way that a hothouse stimulates plants.

Answer (score 1):

You could say a creatively stifling environment, they spoon feed you (I don't think this is right for your context), they molly-coddle you, or patronizing/paternalistic company. It depends on exactly how they are stifling the innovation? Is it a Kafka-esque bureaucracy, is it the hierarchy, is it the stagnation of the company, is it lack of respect for a person, etc.

Comment: I think "stifling" is the usual adjective for this kind of atmosphere, with the literal sense of a place with no air where you can't breathe, and the metaphorical one where all activity is difficult or impossible and people move less or not at all.

Answer (score -1):

Greenhouse conditions don't necessarily stifle innovation on their own, they typically magnify the impact of other things. In English, we call it the **greenhouse effect**.

I don't understand the leap you've made from high tariffs to an environment that stifles creativity. I think you need to add some more information to help your reader make the connection between the two.

Comment: Lack of competition stifles innovation, it's pretty straightforward

Comment: Where does it say "lack of competition" in the paragraph?

Comment: Well, "protecting" domestic manufacturers from foreign competition is what tariffs do, no need to spell that out

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize all your readers are experts in economics. In that case, use "greenhouse effect."

Comment: It has strong environmental connotations, won't do